# Split string before regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, split

I'm trying to insert a tab (\t) before a regex, in a string. Before "**x** days ago", where x is a number between 0-999.

The text I have looks like this:

```
Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon
Fast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! 42 days ago anon
```

Desired output:

```
Great product, fast shipping! \t 22 days ago anon
Fast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! \t 42 days ago anon
```

I am still new to this, and I'm struggling. I've looked around for answers, and found some that are close, but none that are identical.

This is what I have so far:

```
text = 'Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon'
new_text = re.sub(r"\d+ days ago", "\t \d+", text)
print new_text
```

Output:

```
Great product, fast shipping!    \d+ anon
```

Again, what I need is (note the \t):

```
Great product, fast shipping!    22 days ago anon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backreferences in your replacement string. Put parantheses around the `\d+ days ago` to make it a captured group and use `\\1` inside your replacement to refer to this group's text:

```
>>> text = 'Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon'
>>> new_text = re.sub(r"(\d+ days ago)", "\t\\1", text)
>>> print new_text
Great product, fast shipping!    22 days ago anon
```

Answer (score 1):

You were replacing with a regex pattern, and you needed just a `\1` backreference.

In order to just insert a tab before *n days ago*, you can use a look-ahead, and replace the captured number with a `\t\1`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\d+)(?=\s+days\s+ago)')
test_str = u"Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon\nFast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! 42 days ago anon"
subst = u"\t\\1"
print re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Result of a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU2wT2/3):

```
Great product, fast shipping!   22 days ago anon
Fast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks!   42 days ago anon
```

And a [sample program](http://goo.gl/KZwSMN).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead to do zero width insertion and `' '` to find the leading literal space:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt='''\
... Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon
... Fast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! 42 days ago anon'''
>>> repr(re.sub(r' (?=\d+)', ' \t', txt))
"'Great product, fast shipping! \\t22 days ago anon\\nFast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! \\t42 days ago anon'"
```

Note that all the patterns fitting `' \d+'` become `' \t\d+'` which is what I think you are after.

If you want to limit to `' \d+ days ago''` just add that to the lookahead:

```
>>> txt='''\
... Great product, fast shipping! 22 days ago anon
... Fast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! 42 weeks ago anon'''
>>> repr(re.sub(r' (?=\d+ days ago)', ' \t', txt))
"'Great product, fast shipping! \\t22 days ago anon\\nFast shipping. Got an extra free! Thanks! 42 weeks ago anon'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Tabindex = re.search(r"\d days ago",text).start()
text = text[0:Tabindex]+'\t'+text[Tabindex:len(text)]
```